# prepareForSegue() and viewDidLoad() of SecondViewController

Tags: ios, swift

prepareForSegue() method defines an object type of SecondViewController.
Then, it access data member of SecondViewController class and assign "New View Controller" string into this data member. All of things are performed in prepareForSegue() method.

Is viewDidLoad() method of SecondViewController class invoked after prepareForSegue() method of MainViewController class ?

I asked this question because prepareForSegue() initialize the data member declared with String type of SecondViewController class. If What I asked above is true, then I can assign this string member into label.text of SecondViewController class.

Comment: yes you can do that. View did load is called afterwards when your second view controller starts loading.

Comment: this means that loading of a view controller is performed after its own properties( data members or data fields ) are initialized Right ?

Comment: You could initialize your properties using a `init` function if this would be helpful for you. This is definitely called before any view loading funcs. Otherwise set your data from the `prepareForSegue()` fund, which will work fine, too (and yes, before viewDidLoad).

Answer (score 0):

In `prepareForSegue` accessing to the `SecondViewController` you actually trigger its `viewDidLoad`.

It quite obvious if you think about it, you need to have the view loaded to access it.

You can still use other view lifecycle method in the `SecondViewController` like `viewWillAppear` or create a custom `init` for it.